# How much meat do I need to serve 26 adults?

Tags: roasting, bulk-cooking, menu-planning

Hello everyone i am cooking for 26 adults and 4 children 
menu is :

```
rare roast beef served on crusty bread with horseradish
main:
slow roasted pork belly with cider and cream gravy
roasted lamb
served with Mediterranean veg and Yorkshire puddings
```

I really need help with how much raw meat to buy please thank you I am in south africa 
Kind regards Lea

Comment: related http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/59215/67 ; and for holidays http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/36861/67 .  (but those are likely geared towards estimates for overweight Americans)

Comment: As a general guideline (not an answer to your meat question specifically, but for the whole) count on people eating 1/2 kilo (1.1 pnd) each - that is the total for all ingredients. If you have 'dense' foods like rice in the menu, make it less.

Answer (score 8):

Generally speaking, a 1/2 lb per person should be plenty assuming you have some food other than meat they will be eating, and it sounds like you do. I'd recommend buying 15 lbs total and you will definitely have enough.

Since you are going to have multiple meats, that makes it a bit more challenging because you have to guess which is going to be eaten more/less.

[This article](http://www.thekitchn.com/whats-the-right-amount-of-meat-to-serve-per-person-112577) from The Kitchn would actually recommend a bit less than 15 lbs for you since the meat is not really a main dish on it's own in any of your dishes.

Go with 15 lbs to be safe, and just think through how much of each meat you will need.

Comment: I would indeed say 15lbs is probably on the high side, but then: Better safe than sorry. Whenever I cook for more people than my own family, I definitely prefer leftovers over disappointed faces. My family can be easily appeased the next day :)